# Javascript not adding id in address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason this javascript will not add the id of the clicked element into the address bar. It will do everything else correctly.

here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4x7La64s/

so for example if I click on `#introduction` I want it to put the id in the address bar like so: `example.com/page.php/#introduction`

Comment: It is happening because of the event prevention when you do: e.preventDefault();

Comment: 1. Please include the relevant code *in the question itself. 2. Highlight what part of your Javascript you think would do anything to the address bar.

Comment: Note that you're buried inside iframes in jsfiddle.  You don't really have access to change things in the address bar, so you're not going to see anything there.

Comment: thanks @Mindastic I just commented out that line.

Comment: Excellent @YobdDigital. I added the response below with some other code that might result useful. If it really helped you, please consider marking it as the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the prevent default function:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based in your code, after doing:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

You could do something like:

```
var hash = jQuery(this).attr("href"); //Your clicked link
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
  history.pushState(null, null, 'hash'); // This won't make the page jump to the id
} else {
  location.hash = hash; //This will be the fallback for old browsers and this will make the page jump to that id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault`, as the name suggests, prevents the default action from occurring; in the case of an anchor, navigating to the new URL.

A technical definition can be found on Mozilla's Developer Network (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

> Cancels the event if it is cancellable, without stopping further propagation of the event.

Since you are cancelling the event, the browser does not do anything (such as scrolling to the element).

You could add this code without changing anything else:

```
var hash = this.hash;

if ('history' in window && history.pushState) {
    // Add a new state in the browser's history. Does not scroll to the element
    // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState
    history.pushState('', '', hash);
} else {
    // Fallback for old browsers (mainly IE<9). Scrolls to the element
    location.hash = hash;
}
```

The code adds a new entry in the browser's history.

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/toothbrush7777777/108d4356/ for an example.